# yii вывести логи Time Memory на страницу

Tags: yii2

Всем привет. Начал осваивать yii2. Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести в yii2 список логов Time Memory из консоли на страницу для просмотра выполнения запросов и времени за которое запрос выполнился.
Спасибо.

Comment: Добрый вечер. В yii2 есть debug панель, где Вы можете контролировать работу framework-a

Comment: Добрый вечер. Про дебаг панель знаю, но стоит задача вынести данные из вкладки Time  Memory дебаг панели в контроллер, чтоб можно было в админ панеле сделать делегирование прав на просмотр этих данных.

Comment: Смотрите информацию о логировании